# Python PDFMiner error: "No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?"

Tags: python, macos, pdf, document-root, pdf-parsing

I am getting this error "No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?" using my MAC computer with Python 2.7 and [PDFMiner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) version 20110515. 
The pdf files are not damaged because the same program with the same files works on my PC computer! Also I have tried many pdfs and this error exists for all of them. Any ideas of what I should change in my MAC to not to get this error?

Comment: Version 20110515 of PDFMiner is a Beta release, so it may have bugs. Fortunately it's pure Python, which can help make debugging easier. The problem you describe may be due to the way end-of-lines are being handled in the files being parsing. Make sure they're being opened in binary mode, i.e. `fp = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')`. It may also be helpful to run the included `dumppdf.py` utility on the problem files. Lastly, the error may be due to that fact that the Python interpreter you're varies from machine to machine. Universal newline support isn't built-in to all versions of Python.

Answer (score 5):

I found the source of the problem:

I had a method to read all the files in a directory and parse them. Turns out that I had one hidden file in that directory that was not a pdf file!

Here is how I fixed the problem:

```
for filename in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR_NAME):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        #do stuff!
```